# Materialize remove nav background

Tags: html, css, materialize

I'm trying to get an extended nav in my site which looks like this:

```
<nav class="nav-extended">
  <div class="nav-wrapper">

    <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
      <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/?hl=nl"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="https://plus.google.com/discover"><i class="fab fa-google-plus-g"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="https://twitter.com/?lang=nl"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="nav-content">
    <ul class="tabs tabs-transparent">
      <li class="tab"><a href="#">contact us</a></li>
      <li class="tab"><a href="#">blog</a></li>
      <li class="tab"><a href="#">pages</a></li>
      <li class="tab"><a href="#">service</a></li>
      <li class="tab"><a href="#">about us</a></li>
      <li class="tab"><a href="#">home</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

In this navigation, I am trying to remove the upper background where the icons are at. There is a standard red background from Materialize I can't remove.

This is what I tried in my CSS:

```
background-color: none (!important);
background-color: rgba (0, 0, 0, 0);
opacity
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the second background-color and remove the parentheses around !important.

```
background-color: none !important;
```

Answer (score 0):

The default red background is inherited from the nav element. So to override it add a color to your nav-wrapper class, like

```
background-color: white;
```

And, background-color: none is not a valid option. Even if you add transparent background color, it is going to show the parent container's color which is red.

PS: Please add jsfiddle or codePen with your questions whenever possible.

Comment: I can make it white but that doesn't help, I need to see the background around.

Comment: Let me rephrase.. you need the red color for nav-content but not for nav-wrapper. For that just add the white background for .nav-wrapper selector.

Answer (score 0):

Use `background:transparent` in inline css

```
    <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/?hl=nl"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://plus.google.com/discover"><i class="fab fa-google-plus-g"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://twitter.com/?lang=nl"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
 </div>

<div class="nav-content">
    <ul class="tabs tabs-transparent">
        <li class="tab"><a href="#">contact us</a></li>
        <li class="tab"><a href="#">blog</a></li>
        <li class="tab"><a href="#">pages</a></li>
        <li class="tab"><a href="#">service</a></li>
        <li class="tab"><a href="#">about us</a></li>
        <li class="tab"><a href="#">home</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the background or make it transparent with the help of this `background-color: transparent`. You can check in `materialize.css` file about the default properties, if you want to change then you can `override` those as per your need.

```
<head>
<style>
    nav {
        background-color: transparent;
    }

    body {
        background-image: url('./LRNHBJ.jpg');
        background-size: cover;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<nav>

    <div class="nav-wrapper container">
        <a href="#" class="brand-logo black-text">Logo</a>
        <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
            <li>
                <a class="black-text" href="sass.html">Sass</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="black-text" href="badges.html">Components</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="black-text" href="collapsible.html">JavaScript</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
</body>
```

**Materialize.css nav part:**

[image: Materialize-CSS code snippet]

**Transparent Navbar(No background color navbar)**

[image: Demo Image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using materialize and just want to remove the color you can use a materialize class: **N/A transparent**

Your code would be something like that

```
<nav class="nav-extended N/A transparent">
  (...)
</nav>
```

If you want also want to remove the shadows then you can use a materialize class **z-depth-0**

So your code would be like this:

```
<nav class="nav-extended N/A transparent z-depth-0">
  (...)
</nav>
```

You can use these classes on other elements... Just keep in mind this

Remove Color: `class="N/A transparent"`

Remove shadows: `class="z-depth-0"`

You can check these classes in

- [materialize documentation for colors](https://materializecss.com/color.html)
- [materialize documentation for shadow](https://materializecss.com/shadow.html)